# Unique constraint for 2 columns that works both ways

Tags: postgresql

I have a friends table

```
| id | requestor | requestee | status |
```

requestor and requestee are both userIds

I want to have a unique set of relationships so if id:1 requests to be friends with id:2 the visa versa would not be allowed.

I tried adding a unique constraint with the requestor and requestee columns, but that allowed 1 2 if 2 1 existed.

How else can I do this? is there some sort of flag when making a constraint to make it cover both combinations?

I am also open to structuring it differently/ adding new tables if it is the right way to accomplish this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a unique index that always indexes the same order of values:

```
create unique index 
   on friends (least(requestor, requestee), greatest(requestor, requestee));
```

Comment: that works, thanks